# Python redirect output to a file and console by opening new command prompt

Tags: python

I am trying to achieve a functionality where I can open a new command prompt and run some batch commands. Then redirecting the output to a logfile and console on real time. So I am using wtee.exe (ex command: dir 2>&1 | wtee.exe logFile.txt).

Choosing popen over os.system because I need control over the new process (new command prompt)

As I wont be able to use pipe symbol in Popen. I did the below functionality

```
newConsole = Popen(
      ['cmd','/V:ON /K dir 2>&1'],
      creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT
      )
outputLog = Popen(
      [wtee.exe,'logFile.txt'],
      stdin=newConsole.stdout,
      )
```

I can see the log file is generated and also the output in command prompt (on main window and not in new console).

So please help to find out the way how can I print the output in new console opened using subprocess.